# How to print directly to the printer using only Laravel or make a pdf and print it directly from the browser?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to print all the grades by level from a school, I'm working using Laravel and I have searched for the way to do it but I could'nt find the answer.
Do someone here knows how to send a view to be printed directly to the printer? or instead, how to make a pdf with all the grades and then use the pdf software to print? I prefer to not using third party plugins also, could someone give me ligth about this issue?

Comment: This isn’t a code writing service. Please provide any code that you have tried or research that you have done atleast

Comment: If Im asking here is because I did not find info about it after research at Google and Laravel Site, and as my question tell clearly there is no code because I had not write any because I dont know how to achieve this

Comment: I was asking if anyone knows hoe to doit or have any suggestion, what I think it was clearly specify in my question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are ways in 'vanilla' PHP to create PDFs but they're pretty dense imo. You can find out about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php).

Although if you were to rethink your policy on 3rd parties, [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) is a lot easier.

With the latter you can write HTML (and can use the blade templating from laravel) and pass it straight to DOMPDF to render it as is. There are some examples for both in the links above.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

EDIT: It's early and I didn't read your question properly. 
To print trigger a physical print of a page you'll need some javascript. It depends strongly on what printers are there. If they have some sort of print by email function it's easier, just generate the PDF and use MailChimp or something to shoot it off to the printer. Some have FTP or file sharing options also.

If this isn't an option you'll have to load the page and trigger the browser print using the javascript `window.print();` function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I will check this out, I think the best way is throug the browser.